# How do I snap one object into place with the opening of another object? (See picture)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image: Snap]

As you can see, I'm trying to put this object into the opening below it. Is there a quick and easy way to do this? The top model is not rotated exactly correctly to match the opening, although the model is exactly the right size so if it were matching orientation it would fit. I'm looking for a way that I can sort of 'click' the top one into it and it will adjust accordingly.

Comment: I can't really see the problem very well in your screenshot.. Are you looking for something like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6802/599)?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to take [this](http://i.imgur.com/K0FDx4C.png) and put it into [this hole](http://i.imgur.com/4WyZDCO.png). The aren't aligned exactly via rotation but the opening is the same size as the edge of the model so it should fit if rotated correctly, which I'm looking for a way to do automatically.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. Would to work to get it positioned as close as possible, and then join the objects and remove double vertices to connect them? (They could be separated again afterwards)

Comment: Huh, I hadn't thought of that. Getting them close together then merge close verticies. It wouldn't be perfect, but it won't really matter in the long run! I'll post back with results.

Comment: I think it is possible, if the only differences for the border are about rotation, position, and/or scale. **[Here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6376/696)** for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only about location and rotation around the Z axis, it should be as simple as:

1. Select the object you wanna align
2. Go to Editmode <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Select all <kbd>A</kbd>
4. Make sure you are in Vertex Select mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
5. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click a vertex twice, which you wanna use to align location
   (makes it the active vertex)
6. Enable Snapping <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
7. Make it snap to vertices <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
8. Set *Snap Target* to **Active**
9. Grab your object <kbd>G</kbd> and snap it to the other model's corresponding vetex
10. Snap Cursor to Active <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
11. Change *Pivot Point* to **3D Cursor** <kbd>.</kbd>
12. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click a vertex twice, which you wanna use to lineup rotation
    (make it active)
13. Rotate the model <kbd>R</kbd>, constrain to <kbd>Z</kbd> axis and snap your vertex to the corresponding vertex of the other model
    (this can be really tricky, try to make the models a bit transparent to see what you are snapping to)

Not sure if the vertex in step 12 needs to **have the same Z location** as the first vertex... But even then, it should be possible to use any vertex with a bit more effort, to be able to constrain the right rotation axis in step 13 - using a custom transform orientation, which you would have to set up first...

If the models did not align originally, you might be able to snap to edge instead in step 13...

Comment: If the OP doesn't care about changing the position of origin, this would be fine.

Comment: Oh right, didn't think about that... but vertex snapping for active vert seems to work in editmode only. Maybe use a script to correct origin afterwards?

Comment: I would suggest to snap 3D cursor to one vertex first, then add a new empty; Select the object first, then the empty, thus it can work in object mode, since empty snapping can be treated like vertex.