# How can I put an object in the center of the viewport and on top of the floor?

Tags: mesh

I was able to move my object to the center and on top of the floor by adding a vertex right in the middle of the bottom of it and then using a combination of cursor and origin settings. I want to know how to do this without having to add this vertex, since I had to add more geometry to my mesh to get this vertex there.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding correctly, this should help. Try this:

- In *Edit Mode* select the bottom Face
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *cursor to Selected*
- switch with <kbd>Tab</kbd> in *Object Mode*
- In the Tools panel *Set Origin to 3D cursor*
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *cursor to center*
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> again, but choose *selection to cursor*

[image]

Also see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/22893/19287) post

Comment: But that doesn't place the object EXACTLY on the floor does it? I mean it does with the default cube if you use snapping because I believe the cube is exactly 2 units in height. But my object is not like that so when I use the snap it won't place its bottom right on the floor.

Comment: This should work properly since you are resetting the origin point to the middle of the bottom face, then snapping the object via origin point to the cursor (which you already snapped to the world origin). Shouldn't matter how tall your object is. Try it out and see.