# Snap objects to floor

Tags: scripting, add-on

I'm a beginner in blender scripting, in [How to place any object on the 'floor' of a scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22888/how-to-place-any-object-on-the-floor-of-a-scene/117188#117188), [@MACHIN3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/117188/15543) wrote this simple but smart code. Can you explain me the meaning of every line?

```py
import bpy
context = bpy.context

for obj in context.selected_objects:
    mx = obj.matrix_world
    minz = min((mx @ v.co)[2] for v in obj.data.vertices)
    mx.translation.z -= minz
```

In the same question the topic of how can integrate this code in Blender as a button is very interesting, can you help me with this? Actually I'm working with tutorials, Manuals, etc. but I'm afraid my knowledge is not enough.

Comment: Sorry, the format`s code is wrong

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22888/how-to-place-any-object-on-the-floor-of-a-scene/117188#117188

Comment: Hi. If someone wrote the code in another question you should comment on the answer and ask them to explain it there. Also, please only ask one question at a time. Thanks.

Comment: Finds the minimum global coordinate of all vertices, translate the matrix such that this is on global z = 0.   Look at the simple operator template in _`Text Editor > Templates > Python`_  Replace the innards of `main(context)` with body of code above (ie the for loop)

Comment: @batFINGER thank you very much for your help

Comment: ok, finally create the operator an simple panel, as directed by blender's templates, tough i wish add it in 3D view>object>snap  How can do it?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer in

[1][How to place any object on the 'floor' of a scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22888/how-to-place-any-object-on-the-floor-of-a-scene/117188#117188)

My addon append one item in Object>Snap menu